# Numbers that are divisible by the number of primes smaller than them

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\pi(n)$ denote the number of primes less than or equal to $n$ (a.k.a the [prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)).

For certain values of $n$, the value of $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}$ is integer.

Here are the first few examples:

- $n=  8,\pi(n)= 4,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=2$
- $n= 27,\pi(n)= 9,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=3$
- $n= 30,\pi(n)=10,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=3$
- $n= 33,\pi(n)=11,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=3$
- $n= 96,\pi(n)=24,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=4$
- $n=100,\pi(n)=25,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=4$
- $n=120,\pi(n)=30,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=4$
- $n=330,\pi(n)=66,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=5$
- $n=335,\pi(n)=67,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=5$
- $n=340,\pi(n)=68,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=5$
- $n=350,\pi(n)=70,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=5$
- $n=355,\pi(n)=71,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=5$
- $n=360,\pi(n)=72,\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=5$

$\textbf{Has it been proved that }\mathbf{\forall{k>1},\exists{n}:\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=k}$?

Two aspects which "intuitively" support this statement are:

1. The [prime-number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), which implies $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}\approx\ln{n}$.
2. There seem to be several such values of $n$ for each value of $k$.

But I'm not sure how either one of them can be used in order to establish a proof.

Comment: k = 11 only occurs once so the "intuition" seems shaky.

Comment: @daniel: Hmmmm... Thanks. My initial purpose was to ask if it had been proved that there were infinitely many values of $n$ such that $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}\in\mathbb{N}$. But after noticing that it occurred for quite many values of $n$, I decided to ask about the somewhat stronger statement above. Now I'm starting to think that perhaps the "original" statement is not so "obviously true".

Comment: How far did you check, out of curiosity?

Comment: @daniel: around $n=10000$ (again, with the "original" question in mind).

Comment: Your idea is true through k=14 (which causes my computer to smoke).

Comment: @daniel Which number satisfies $k=11$?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt: $175197/\pi(175197) = 11.$

Comment: @daniel: What question in MO?

Comment: @daniel: It would be more appropriate if he/she added that in **their answer**. I don't think it's a good idea that I update my question according to other people's answers (let alone, according to comments made on other people's answers).

Comment: On second thought there is no obligation on your part, so I will just mention here that the question (and the proof below) were noted in another question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139934/a-question-for-the-prime-counting-function.

Comment: @daniel: Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With respect to your question if there is, for each $k$, an $n$ such that $\dfrac{n}{\pi(n)}=k$ I think the answer is affirmative. If we consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{\pi(x)}$, we can prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ (by the prime number theorem or by more elementary bounds). If $f$ were continuous, as $f(2) = 2$, we should have an intermediate value such that $f(x)=k$. This naive approach doesn't work (as $f$ is not continuous). However, we can do something similar:

We know that there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)<k$ and $f(n+1)\geq k$ (as $f$ tends to infinite, it can't always be bounded by $k$). If $f(n+1)=k$, then we're done. If not, $f(n+1)>k$. This two inequalities can be rewritten as $n < k \pi(n)$ and $n+1 > k\pi(n+1)$. This means that $$k \pi (n+1) < n+1 < k\pi(n) + 1$$  That is $k(\pi(n+1) - \pi(n)) < 1$. This implies that $\pi(n)=\pi(n+1)$. But then, $$k\pi(n+1) = k\pi(n) < n+1 < k\pi(n)+1$$ Absurd, since $n+1$ is an integer in between two consecutive integers.

Comment: ${}{}{}$Nicely done!

Comment: And if n / π (n) drops below k again for a slightly larger n, then the same argument applies and we have another solution. The gap between primes will on average be a bit larger than k at this point, so n / π (n) may never become less than k again.

Comment: Had a hunch that prime-gap was "behind all this". Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is proved by S.W.Golomb.
I cannot resist to show a piece of my work:http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1398

Comment: "An exact formula for $\pi(n)$ which holds infinitely often"? Does that mean it **doesn't** hold in certain cases? Also, for the lazy ones who haven't read the article yet (such as myself) - what is that formula? Or do you merely prove that one such formula exists?

Comment: BTW, one can easy write-down a formula (using a couple of $\sum$, etc), to compute this value precisely for any value of $n$. The formula will "act" in a similar manner to a computer program (as you know, every computer program can be written as a formula). So I'm not sure that there is anything "new" about saying that there's an exact formula for $\pi(n)$.

Comment: @barakmanos check here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139934/a-question-for-the-prime-counting-function

Comment: I see, but you have an "occurs infinitely often" there too, which I still don't quite understand. Does the formula hold for **every** value of $n$ or **only** for infinitely many values of $n$? (just out of curiosity, since it is not directly related to the question at hand).

Comment: @barakmanos It holds infinitely often but not always. It is impossible to hold for every $n>1$ because $n$ cannot have always a positive divisor and the fraction would yield a non integer value some times.

Comment: It just so happen that I have a formula which gives the number of primes less than or equal to $n$ for **every** given value of $n$. I also have a formula which gives the $n$th prime number for every given value of $n$. But I see no "breaking news" in either one of them, because as I told you, they sort of "emulate" a computer program. I can give you those formulas if it helps...

Comment: I am aware that such formulas exist and I do not claim that my formula is actually a groundbreaking result.It is just something which is worth to be mentioned since it "hits" the exact value at once without computer or any algorithm.Imagine for example that you know from some theorem that $\pi(10^{300})\mid 10^{300}$. Then you would be able to know the exact value of the prime counting function.

Comment: "At once" is a matter of definition. $\ln(n)$ by itself is not something that you can calculate "at once and without using a computer". In fact, it requires an infinite number of operations in order to be calculated precisely, hence we all (including computers) use an approximation. By the way, a similar claim can be made about division - or even multiplication - of large numbers (except for the fact that those **do** require only a finite number of operations). In any case, the question here is how exactly you define an "immediate formula", and I'm not sure that there's a good answer to it...

Comment: Anyway my friend I do not wish to extend this to a philosophical conversation.It is just that I had the same question as you before a few years as an undergraduate.( because I wanted to prove what I prove in arXiv) and when I saw your question I was a little bit touched.And again I do not believe that I prove anything great but you never know when something will be usefull in the future! :)

Comment: OK, gotcha, thank you for the enlightening information above :)

Comment: This was in AMM vol. 69. no.1 1962. It might be good to include the full cite in case someone wants to look it up.+1 for the information.